# Why some of the drones are not moving?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class DronesManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<GameObject> drones = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        drones = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Drone").ToList();

        StartCoroutine(MoveDrone());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveDrone()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < drones.Count; i++)
        {
            var drone = drones[Random.Range(0, drones.Count)];
            if (drone.GetComponent<DroneControl>().go == false)
            {
                drone.GetComponent<DroneControl>().movingSpeed = 0.5f;
                drone.GetComponent<DroneControl>().go = true;
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        }
    }
}
```

I loop over the List of drones in the coroutine but each time some of the drones stay not move.
What I want to do is to loop over drones list and move each drone but each time to randomly move one from the list. until all drones are moving.

The problem is because it's random some drones stay and never picked.

The script that attached to each drone and move it :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DroneControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movingSpeed;
    public bool go = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(go)
        {
            transform.position -= transform.forward * movingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I tried :

Still some drones stay and not moving.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class DronesManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private List<GameObject> drones = new List<GameObject>();
    private static System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        drones = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Drone").ToList();
        
        StartCoroutine(MoveDrone());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveDrone()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < drones.Count; i++)
        {
            var numbers = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, drones.Count));
            var droneIndices = numbers.OrderBy(a => rnd.Next()).ToList();
            var drone = drones[droneIndices[i]];

            if (drone.GetComponent<DroneControl>().go == false)
            {
                drone.GetComponent<DroneControl>().movingSpeed = 0.5f;
                drone.GetComponent<DroneControl>().go = true;
            }

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using new random value each time. They are likely to repeat. Solution would be to keep track of the moved ones and to exclude that value from the array of possible indices. Or just use indices array 0-n and shuffle them, then take them as they come.

Replace

```
var drone = drones[Random.Range(0, drones.Count)];
```

with

```
private static System.Random rnd  = new System.Random();


var numbers = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, drones.Count));
var droneIndices = numbers.OrderBy(a => rnd.Next()).ToList();
var drone = drones[droneIndices[i]];
```

Comment: Sorry I edited code a few times, don't have complier at hand so please do tell if it doesn't compile so I can edit again.

Comment: Next on rnd is not exist getting error :  missing reference ? rnd.Next

Comment: @chkfmysfms I am referencing c# Random. Its from the System namespace. Edited to not require using

Comment: I tried it but still some drones are not moving.  I updated my question in the bottom with the updated code.

Comment: @chkfmysfms can you determine what percentage of the drones isn't moving, and is that number changing throughout different runs? I.E. is it one drone always, is it half of them, or random chunk of whole array?

Comment: @chkfmysfms Did you manage to find a solution for your problem? If you are still facing it, it would be helpful to share info from the last question I asked you, if not, please share answer for people who come across something similar.